# Pandas Complex GroupBy and Apply on Machine Learning Dataset

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a dataset i am using for a Machine Learning Dataset. My dataframe is listed below.

dataframe = df

```
      memid     year     code1     code2    ....... n amount of columns
        1       2014      8888      654
        2       2016      13456     4353
        2       2016      12345     3333
        1       2014      123333    1111 
        1       2016      55555     2222 
        1       2016      99999     2222
```

My goal is to roll up the dataset and add year as a measure in the column names to the whole dataframe (ie. n number of columns) my table structure below is my goal

Goal Dataframe below:

```
 memid    code1_2014     code1_2015     code1_2016      code2_2014       code2_2015     code2_2016
   1      8888, 123333                  55555, 99999     654, 1111                          2222
   2                                    13456, 12345                                     4353, 3333
```

the goal of this code is to achieve the above column structure for all columns in the dataset except memid. I know this is a complex groupby and .apply or join method however i cannot achieve the goal.

Please Help! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
grpd_vals = df.pivot_table(
    index='memid',
    columns='year',
    aggfunc=lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x.values)
).unstack().to_frame().reset_index()
```

gives:

[image]

Then build a column to hold your new column names:

```
grpd_vals['col'] = grpd_vals['level_0'] + '_'+grpd_vals['year'].astype(str)
```

then group again:

```
grpd_vals.pivot_table(
    index='memid',
    columns='col',
    values=0,
    aggfunc=lambda x: x
)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: thank you this worked!! however, lets say there are multiple rows with blank data. the dataset is looking like 4619,4619,,,,,,,,4619,4619 as an example, when it should just read 4619 as one instance, not multiple.

Comment: Awesome. Please accept the answer to show that it worked for you.

Comment: oop, didn't read the rest of your comment. I guess in the concat function you could filter out nans like `lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x.values if pd.notnull(i))`

Comment: yah, see my above comment. replace the string agg func with `lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x.values if pd.notnull(i))` and they won't show up

Comment: or, if you've got string columns with empty values, you should use `i != ''`  instead of `pd.notnull(i)`

Comment: the i != '' worked! the last part would be to remove the duplicate entries, as an example if a year column has multiple same records code1_2014 reads 25003,25003 when i just want it to be 25003 instead of the dubplicate entry.

Comment: please see my comment above

Comment: `lambda x: ','.join(set(str(i) for i in x.values if pd.notnull(i)))` wrapping the iterator in `set` will return unique values

Comment: awesome it worked! i need to convert this back to a dataframe, for anaylsis, not in a pivot table format, while i have you is there a way to convert this back to a dataframe easily?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199917/discussion-between-greg-data-and-james-scott).

Answer (score 0):

May be not as straightforward as the earlier one but here's my try.

`grouped = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby(['memid','year']).aggregate(lambda x: list(x)))
 grouped.columns = ['_'.join(str(i)) for i in list(grouped.index.values)]
 grouped = grouped.reset_index(level= 1, drop=True)
 final = grouped.groupby(grouped.index).aggregate(lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist])`